# What is difference between the various ways of writing a component using React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, components, arrow-functions

I'm here studying React and from time to time, when I'm looking at component creation codes, I see 4 different syntaxes and I wanted to understand if there is any difference between the 4, I really want to understand even if there isn't one better than the other, I want at least see the most used. These are the ones I always see:

```
export const Home = () => {
}


export function Home() { 
}


function Home() {
}
export default Home;


const Home = () => { 
}
export default Home;
```

Comment: Well, there are 2 ways to write function components, `function` keyword and ES6 arrow notation, and there are 2 ways to export them, named and default export. Javascript docs cover these pretty extensively.

Comment: To be clear, I don't think there's much a difference between how you define and export your components, it's going to mostly come down to personal opinion which you like better, or if you are working on a team, what has previously been established as a coding standard.

Comment: There's another one using class, called class component. In your example code almost of all is same, functional component. It's just different when declaration, using function or arrow function, and just export or export default.

Comment: @edhi.uchiha but class is not losing space in component creation? I've seen some articles that suggest always using functional components and not class components anymore.

Comment: Class components are still valid, but when React hooks were finally released and function components could have state and lifecycle... well, why keep using class components? It's probably been almost 2 years since I wrote a class-component for work.

Comment: @EltonSantos yes, for few reason functional component is better.

Comment: I've almost completely forgotten how to write class components. LOL

Comment: To be completely honest I think when approaching React you ***should*** start with class components as there is a small set of lifecycle methods (`componentDidMount`, `componentDidUpdate`, and `componentWillUnmount`) that really drive the when, what, and where of the things you do during the life of a component. Once you've a strong grasp of the component lifecycle, transferring this knowledge to React hooks is a near trivial matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is only two ways to declare a component in React (function and class component), It is recommended by react team to use functional component because of the *this* problem.

you shared 4 types of functional components which are really ONE type (functional component) but the difference is the function syntax in JS itself. JS has two ways of defining functions as follows:

```
function foo() {} //regular function.

const foo = () => {} // arrow ( fat ) function.
```

The last one is preferable also because of the overwhelming and confusing *this* problem in JS itself.  you could search to learn about this l.. But arrow function as I said is the most preferable way.

After you have declared your component, you will be - mostly - in need to *export*..
In Js there’s two ways of *export* (default and named export).

Mostly you will use *default* export with your functional component. So I recommend number 4 of the examples you have shared.